# parse 'page 1 of x' - the best method (ruby/mechanize/nokogiri)

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

what is the best **method** using **ruby/mechanize/nokogiri** to go/click **through all pages** in case there is more than 1 page I need to access/click on? For example [here Page 1 of 34](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=251) Should I click the page number or next? Or is out there any better solution?

Comment: Oops indeed misread your question. I do not have any experience with clicking on links using Ruby. Hopefully someone else is able to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the link ">" takes you to the next page, and it does not appear if you are on the last page.  So:

```
page = ... # fetch the first page
loop do
  # process the page
  break unless link = page.link_with(:text=>'>')
  page = link.click
end
```

Comment: @Wayne. As usual thank you so much. I will test/try and post the result here.But I already know that it will work.Everything you post works...

Comment: You're welcome.  I don't know about _everything_.  I didn't test this fragment, so who knows?

Comment: I added bit of your code ad the end of a procedure that processes the page and then it the procedure calls itself in case the is new page. Lovely.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out scrubyt. It's described as "mechanize on steroids". It has dedicated method for clicking through pages.

Comment: thank you for that suggestion. So can I use scrubyt with mechanize?

Comment: Scrubyt itself uses mechanize so you don't have to. It concentrates on crawling and scraping.